# Regarding Blocks method in textract using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, text-extraction

In this code given below-

```
const _ = require("lodash");
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const config = require("./config");

aws.config.update({
  accessKeyId: config.awsAccesskeyID,
  secretAccessKey: config.awsSecretAccessKey,
  region: config.awsRegion
});

const textract = new aws.Textract();

const getText = (result, blocksMap) => {
  let text = "";

  if (_.has(result, "Relationships")) {
    result.Relationships.forEach(relationship => {
      if (relationship.Type === "CHILD") {
        relationship.Ids.forEach(childId => {
          const word = blocksMap[childId];
          if (word.BlockType === "WORD") {
            text += `${word.Text} `;
          }
          if (word.BlockType === "SELECTION_ELEMENT") {
            if (word.SelectionStatus === "SELECTED") {
              text += `X `;
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }

  return text.trim();
};

const findValueBlock = (keyBlock, valueMap) => {
  let valueBlock;
  keyBlock.Relationships.forEach(relationship => {
    if (relationship.Type === "VALUE") {

      relationship.Ids.every(valueId => {
        if (_.has(valueMap, valueId)) {
          valueBlock = valueMap[valueId];
          return false;
        }
      });
    }
  });

  return valueBlock;
};

const getKeyValueRelationship = (keyMap, valueMap, blockMap) => {
  const keyValues = {};
  console.log("Hello1");
  const keyMapValues = _.values(keyMap);

  keyMapValues.forEach(keyMapValue => {
    const valueBlock = findValueBlock(keyMapValue, valueMap);
    const key = getText(keyMapValue, blockMap);
    const value = getText(valueBlock, blockMap);
    keyValues[key] = value;
    console.log("Hello2");
  });

  return keyValues;
};

const getKeyValueMap = blocks => {
  const keyMap = {};
  const valueMap = {};
  const blockMap = {};
  console.log("Hello3");

  let blockId;
  blocks.forEach(block => {
    blockId = block.Id;
    blockMap[blockId] = block;
    console.log("Hello4");
    if (block.BlockType === "KEY_VALUE_SET") {
      if (_.includes(block.EntityTypes, "KEY")) {
        keyMap[blockId] = block;
        console.log("Hello5a");
      } else {
        valueMap[blockId] = block;
        console.log("Hello5b");
      }
    }
  });

  return { keyMap, valueMap, blockMap };
};




module.exports = async buffer => {
    const params = {
      DocumentLocation: {


        S3Object:{
            Bucket : "<data>",
            Name : "<data>"
        }
      },
      FeatureTypes: ["FORMS"]
    };
    const params1 = {
        JobId:"<data>"

    };





  const request = textract.startDocumentAnalysis(params);
  const request1 = textract.getDocumentAnalysis(params1);
  console.log("A");

        if(request1){

  console.log("B");

  const data1 = await request.promise();

        if (data1){
    console.log("C");
        if (data1 && data1.Blocks) {
        console.log("D");

    const { keyMap, valueMap, blockMap } = getKeyValueMap(data1.Blocks);
    const keyValues = getKeyValueRelationship(keyMap, valueMap, blockMap);

    return keyValues;
  }
    }
  }
  return undefined;
};
```

The output of this code is-

```
A
B
C
undefined
```

This clearly means that data1.Blocks is returning a false value. This code is to read the pdf file using textract. Also when I remove-

```
if (data1 && data1.Blocks)
```

I get the following-

```
A
B
C
D
Hello3
(node:2975) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at getKeyValueMap
```

Why is the data1.Blocks empty and how to resolve the issue to give the desired output as a list of extracted words from the pdf in json format.

Comment: Instead of apologizing for the  bulk of commented code, please remove it after posting it here.

Comment: @desertnaut I have removed the comments.